# View is not rotating with respect to the device orientation,in my iPhone app

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode4, uiinterfaceorientation, landscape-portrait

In my iPhone app,  I have the following code to rotate the Views with respect to the device orientation.

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    // Return YES for supported orientations

    return YES;
}
```

When the device is rotated to landscape mode the view is not rotating.

I have tried  `return (interfaceOrientation == UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeLeft);`

It didn't work, how can I do this?  That class contains one searchbar, table view like this[image]

thanx in advance

Comment: Where did you put that code that you posted?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
I think the reason should be the below issue:

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    // Return YES for supported orientations

    return YES;
}


"You should write return YES; in every viewController in your Application. Even in one class if you write return No;  it will not work obviously..."
```